# React child don't know when parent state changed

Tags: reactjs

My component structure is

```js
// parent

const Parent = () => {

  const [value, setValue] = useState<string>("");
   

  return (
     <PropsDrilling value={value} setValue={setValue} />
   )
}

// prop-drilling
const PropDrilling = ({value, setValue}) => {

   return <Child value={value} setValue={setValue} />
}

// child
const Child = ({value, setValue}) => {
   const onChangeValue = (v) => setValue(v);

   return (
       <>
         <button onClick={() => onChangeValue('1')}>1</button>
         <button onClick={() => onChangeValue('2')}>2</button>
         <button onClick={() => onChangeValue('3')}>3</button>
         <div>{value}</div>
       </>
    )
}
```

setValue event arrives at parent component and parent state changed.

However, the value in child component doesn't changed.

I tested it on propdrilling component using useEffect.

Propdrilling component noticed that value changed.

Why child component don't know that value changed.

---

onChangeValue event call setValue function and setValue operate properly.

Comment: What value are you expecting to show up? You're calling the setter with `e.target.value` which refers to the empty value of the button.

Comment: Yes, the issue is the empty e.target.value. Recreated the issue, and it works with hard-coded values, for example.

Comment: Can you confirm that you want to do this with button tag I'm guessing  you want to do this with input tag ?

Comment: I apologize for the lack of examples of my code. I update examples of my code. thanks a lot.

Comment: you said onChangeValue it works my question is when it's not worked? can yo add example?

Comment: This should have thrown already but you have an error with your naming of PropsDrilling. I don’t think that’s the cause though.

Comment: @MUHAMMADILYAS 
No, it always wort. I mean It always works properly. I don't know why the state in child component did not change

Answer (score 0):

The example code you have provide is working fine.
The only issue was in your **Parent** return you are using **PropsDrilling**  but your component name is **PropDrilling**.
Try the below code.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  return (
    <>
      <h1>state vale {value}</h1>
      <PropDrilling value={value} setValue={setValue} />
    </>
  );
};

// prop-drilling
const PropDrilling = ({ value, setValue }) => {
  return <Child value={value} setValue={setValue} />;
};

const Child = ({ value, setValue }) => {
  const onChangeValue = (v) => setValue(v);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => onChangeValue("1")}>1</button>
      <button onClick={() => onChangeValue("2")}>2</button>
      <button onClick={() => onChangeValue("3")}>3</button>
      <div>{value}</div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Sorry for late. I Update code